# Plotly add_trace() function very slow

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Is there any way to improve add_trace?  I tried to use add_traces and pass all the traces at once, but it didn't change anything in regards to the execution time.

Comment: You'll receive more answers if you provide sample code.  How to you feed add_trace?  Otherwise no one will now how to help.